# calculating selected contrasts with emmeans within treatment

Tags: multiple-comparisons, contrasts, lsmeans

I have a dataset that has data collected at 8 different timepoints and in 5 different treatment groups, and want to do multiple pairwise comparisons. However, I want to run comparisons only between treatments within timepoints (66 comparisons) and between timepoints within treatments (99 comparisons), since for example the comparison of treatment 1, timepoint 1 with treatment 2, timepoint 5, makes no sense and should not be corrected for (396 comparisons).
I used `model.int <- lmerTest::lmer (y ~ treatment : timepoint + (1 | ID))` to run the mixed effect model, `model.emm <- emmeans::emmeans(model.int, 'timepoint')` to calculate estimated marginal means (aka least-squares means) based on this model, and `pairwise.model.emm <- emmeans::contrast(model.emm, method = 'pairwise')` for the pairwise comparisons. Within this approach, I tried both the by and the simple option, but they do not result in what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I would do:

```
EMM <- emmeans(model.int, ~ treatment * timepoint, nesting = NULL)
pairs(EMM, simple = "each")
```

Note that the `emmeans()` call needs to specify *both* factors.

That said, I must misunderstand something because if there are 8 time points and 5 treatments, then there are $8 \times {5\choose2} = 8 \times 10 = 80$ pairwise comparisons of 5 treatments at each of 8 time points -- not 66 as stated. Similarly, there are $5 \times {8\choose2} = 5\times28 = 140$ (not 99) pairwise comparisons of 8 time points with each of 5 treatments. Finally, there are ${40\choose2}=780$ (not 396) pairwise comparisons of the 40 factor combinations.

#### Addendum

I added `nesting = NULL` to force bypassing the grouping imposed by the detection of nests in the empty-cells structure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this gives me the following error message:  `NOTE: A nesting structure was detected in the fitted model:
    treatment%in% (treatment*timepoint), timepoint%in% (treatment*timepoint)`  And by the way, you are right about the number of pairwise comparisons, but my dataset does not havve all parameters taken at every timepoint, and some specific measurments could not be taken on one of the timpoint in one of the groups. This reduced the actual number of comparisons.

Comment: That's actually not an error message, it is just a message. Clearly, you have a lot of holes in the data, because that's the explanation of the message. You can add `nesting = NULL` to the `emmeans` call.You'll get a lot of non-estimable comparisons, but you're expecting them.

Comment: Excellent, it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great. I wonder also if the nesting thing would have been averted if your model formula in the `lmer`call had used `*` instead of `:`. That is, your model excludes the main effects of both factors and that's why it thinks the factors are nested.

Comment: Yes, the model including the main effects did not have the nesting issue, but my model selection based on BIC was in favour of the less complex model with interaction only.

Comment: Hmmm. They're exactly the same model, parameterized differently. So should have same BIC.

Comment: FWIW, your question exposed a subtle bug in my package. The two factors are detected as being nested in each other, hence in themselves. I made a correction that detects and takes care of such situations. So future versions will work right the first time.

Comment: Great, thanks! I installed the update and it works. Oh, and of course you were right about the BICs: they are the same.